# Is there any graph that depicts the deviation of real gases from Charle's law?

Tags: homework, gas-laws

I am looking for a graph that shows the basic deviation of a gas from the Charle's law. The graph should be for different values of constant pressures.This would help me evaluate how gases follow ideal behavior for low pressures and high temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the van der Waals equation wikipedia page for a start ... it gives an explanation of one of the most common modifications of the ideal gas law that allows for modeling of deviations from ideality in the way you describe.  This approach is quite nice in my opinion, because it includes two coefficients (a and b) that account for specific deviations for a given gas ... a scales with the strength of intermolecular interactions, and b accounts for the actual volume of the gas molecules.

You should be able to use that information to do what you want to do regarding Charles Law.  The graph on the page shows isotherms, but you should be able to generate the isobar curves that you are after with a little bit of work.